# .NET 2.0: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: sockets, youtube, youtube-api, windows-server-2000, youtube.net-api

Scenario:

- I try to post a video to YouTube with the following code:

  YouTubeEntry createdEntry = service.Upload(newEntry);
- This works fine on my developer machine (running Windows XP).
- It fails on a Win2k server (running .NET 2.0) with the following error:

2010-07-15||01:14:08 PM||An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine||System||||   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
-->   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

My Question:

> - How should I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check to ensure that you are not being blocked by firewalls or TCP filtering on the server
2. Run a network trace to see what traffic is actually being communicated from your server
3. Check HTTP KeepAlive is disabled (seeing a lot of people having issues with this on)
4. [Google it](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=An+established+connection+was+aborted+by+the+software+in+your+host+machine&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=CxQaFqEw_TKndBZHuzASm9qyBBgAAAKoEBU_Qv_-t&fp=f71f34b6e21b2e38) for any other possible reasons that this could fail on your server.

Comment: +1: It turns out that the firewall was interrupting the communication because I specified the wrong MIME type. Thanks!